# Inequality about the most common divergent series

Tags: summation, divergent-series

We know that:

$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+....$ is a divergent series.

I have a small problem about this series.

Show that:  $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+....+\frac{1}{2^{2006}} >50$

How to prove this one?

Can you use a basic knowledge to explain for a 14 years old student?

Comment: I cannot see what kind of series that expression is.

Answer (score 3):

You even have more:
\begin{align}
1&+\frac 12+\underbrace{\frac 13+\frac 14}_{>\tfrac24=\tfrac12}+\underbrace{\frac 15+\frac 16+\frac17+\frac18}_{>\tfrac48=\tfrac12}+\underbrace{\frac 19+\frac 1{10}+\frac1{11}+\frac1{12}+\frac 1{13}+\frac1{14}+\frac1{15}+\frac1{16}}_{>\tfrac8{16}=\tfrac12}+\\
&+\dotsm+\underbrace{\frac 1{2^{2005}+1}+\frac 1{2^{2005}+2}\dotsm+\frac1{2^{2006}}}_{>\tfrac{2^{2005}}{2^{2006}}=\tfrac12} >1+2006\cdot\frac12=\color{red}{1004}.
\end{align}

---

Answer (score 2):

Notice $1+\frac{1}{2}+\dots + \frac{1}{n} =\int\limits_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor } \geq \int\limits_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{ x  } = \ln(n+1)$

We conclude your sum is at least $\ln(2^ {2006} +1)$ and the rest is easy.

---

A basic way to prove it is by noticing

$\frac{1}{2^ n} + \frac{1}{2^n + 1} + \dots + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}-1}> \frac{2^ n}{2^{n+1}} = \frac{1}{2}$ and notice we can split the sum into way more than $100$ of these sums.

Comment: one possibility is to note $e^ {50} < 4^ {50}=2^ {100} < 2^ {2006}+1$

Comment: I know this prove, but can you solve it basically?

Comment: I posted another solution, please ask what you want clearly from the start !!!

Comment: oh yeah, thank you !